# If/Then Pandas Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to put in a Pandas condition that basically assigns a new value to an existing condition if it meets the criteria. The following psuedo code explains further what I mean:

if postal code is 33707 AND number of bedrooms equals 2
then rent = SquareFeet * 1200

So far the closest I have come to matching this is:

```
df.loc[(df['PostalCode'] == 33707) & (df['BedroomsTotal'] == 2), 'Rent'] = df['LivingArea'] * 2
print(df['Rent'])
```

Comment: You probably want either `np.where` or `np.select` if you have more than 2 conditions

Comment: This should work. What else do you expect?

Comment: Can you update with an example dataframe to make this a running example? Then people can experiment and post based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better to use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for such cases:

```
import numpy as np
df['Rent'] = np.where(df['PostalCode'].eq(33707) & df['BedroomsTotal'].eq(2), df['LivingArea'] * 2, df.Rent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to work with conditions

```
conditions = [((df['postalcode'] ==373370) & (df['bedroomtotal']==2)), 
               ((df['livingarea'] ==12000)
& condition2
& condition3] 

choices = [2,4, 5]. #your choices of multiplicator

import numpy as np

df['rent'] = np.select(conditions, choices*df['livingarea'], default='some value')
```